# Any Ruby AMF clients out there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amf, flash-media-server, wowza

I'm looking for a way to push/receive AMF0 / AMF3 messages in Ruby(Rails).

From what I read rubyAMF can only act as a server.

What I need is a library that allows client access to FMS/Wowza.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As the developer of RocketAMF http://github.com/warhammerkid/rocket-amf, I don't know of any AMF libraries that can act as clients out of the box. However, if you're interested in it, it shouldn't be that difficult to reverse the server code in RocketAMF to work as a client. You would just write a serializer for RocketAMF::Request that uses the standard message calling style (`#<RocketAMF::Request:0x10167b658 @headers=[], @messages=[#<RocketAMF::Message:0x10167ae88 @response_uri="/1", @data=["session stirng", 42.0], @target_uri="App.helloWorld">], @amf_version=3>`). Then you would write a deserializer for RocketAMF::Response.

I'll try to put together a new RocketAMF build in the next couple days that can communicate with FMS, but it's not a guarantee.

Comment: Wow that would be so cool if you would add a functionality like that.

Comment: Are you just trying to make AMF calls, or do you need RTMP support as well? RTMP is almost impossible to support due to a lack of documentation. However, AMF call support is pretty simple.